# TFTP C++ not receiving ACK

Tags: c++, udp, client, tftp

I am writing a TFTP Client using C++. I was able to send a read request using "octet" mode to a default TFTP Client (tftpd32). The problem is that I am unable to send the ACK back at the regular TFTP respond. I am getting the following error:

```
Connection received from 127.0.0.1 on port 51401 [27/07 23:03:15.612]
Read request for file <test.txt>. Mode octet [27/07 23:03:15.612]
Using local port 51402 [27/07 23:03:15.612]
Connection received from 127.0.0.1 on port 51401 [27/07 23:03:18.624]
Unexpected request 4 from peer [27/07 23:03:18.624]
Returning EBADOP to Peer [27/07 23:03:18.624]
```

Why I am able to send the RRQ but not the ACK using the same method?

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to find out what exactly is beeing send over the wire. Maybe that makes it easier to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a not well conformed ACK packet?
It looks like you are sending a request with an ACK opcode…

The form of the ACK packet from  RFC 1350:

```
                 2 bytes     2 bytes
                 ---------------------
                | Opcode |   Block #  |
                 ---------------------
```

where opcode=4